# Does this datetime use milliseconds as time unit?

Tags: python, datetime

For example:

```
import datetime

begin = datetime.datetime.now()

results = process(lines)

end = datetime.datetime.now()

print('Time spent: {}\n'.format(end-begin))
```

It reports:

```
Time spent:  0:00:00.005437
```

Does this mean the process function only take 0.005 millseconds? It seems too little for my code, since it's quite heavy processing. My question is, does the datetime.now() use millsecond or second as time unit?

Comment: It is 5 milliseconds, not 0.005. The format is `hours:minutes:seconds`.

Comment: Does it mean it is 0.005 seconds, so 5 millseconds? @Selcuk

Comment: That's correct. You can also get it in microseconds numerically by using `(end - begin).microseconds`.

Comment: Besides, I'd say Python's datetime doesn't represent a physical quantity that has a ***unit***. It's a datatype to represent date and time (of a certain calendar), and it has a ***precision***, which is microseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `datetime.datetime` difference results in a `datetime.timedelta` instance

Its string representation is given by

```
def __str__(self):
    mm, ss = divmod(self._seconds, 60)
    hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
    s = "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hh, mm, ss)
    if self._days:
        def plural(n):
            return n, abs(n) != 1 and "s" or ""
        s = ("%d day%s, " % plural(self._days)) + s
    if self._microseconds:
        s = s + ".%06d" % self._microseconds
    return s
```

The format is so `hour:minute:second.microsecond`

---

In your case that makes

- `5437` microsecond
- `5` millisecond
- `0.005437` second

---

So 200 runs of that will make a second

Answer (score 0):

**Refer Official Documentation for more details**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

class datetime.time

An idealized time, independent of any particular day, assuming that every day has exactly 24*60*60 seconds. (There is no notion of “leap seconds” here.) Attributes: hour, minute, second, microsecond, and tzinfo.

When I implemented your code I got this

`import datetime

begin = datetime.datetime.now()

end = datetime.datetime.now()

print('Time spent: {}\n'.format(end-begin))`

O/P: Time spent: 0:00:00.000014

**So the unit time is in millisecond which is more than enough for processing**

Comment: `So the unit time is in millisecond` why ? You didn't mention at all milliseconds before , also I don't see any value which has miliseconds as unit, see my answer